# Why method returns false?

Tags: c#

This method returns `false`. I can not understand why

```
private bool SomeMethod()
{
    return new byte[0] == new byte[0];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating two arrays of bytes. The two arrays have different memory addresses and comparing the different addresses return false

```
bool result = (new byte[0] == new byte[0]);
Console.WriteLine(result);

......
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0                    // zero int for size in the evaluation stack
IL_0002:  newarr      System.Byte     // create an array of zero bytes 
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0                    // zero int for size in the evaluation stack
IL_0008:  newarr      System.Byte     // create another array of zero bytes
IL_000D:  ceq                         // compare the address of the two arrays
IL_000F:  stloc.0     // result
IL_0010:  ldloc.0     // result
IL_0011:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating two new arrays and doing a reference compare. When I say reference I mean the location in memory where each lives. Since they aren't the same thing it will always fail.

It would return true if you instead did;

```
   byte[] a = new byte[0];
   byte[] b = a;
   return a == b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are reference types. Each instance has its own reference, which means they won't be equal.